# Options for a voice recording web application

Tags: web-applications, voice-recording

I need to create a web application that allows the user to record voice and save it on a server.

I have searched around to find options, both on Google and on StackOverflow, but it seems that none of those I found are suitable:
Flash - Seems to be dying.
Java applet - Dead already.
HTML 5 - Too early. Although progress are being made, not many browsers have implement audio recording and those that have are still experiementing with it.

So it seems that I either have to select a dead or dying platform or go with one that isn't yet fully up and running.

Or are there other options out there that I have missed? Maybe I have misjudged Flash and/or Java applets?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is dead on mobile. On the desktop it's doing pretty well actually, with an install base of around 95%. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#Desktop_operating_systems

It has a much better adoption rate than HTML5 will have for several more years.

Since you prefer HTML5 though, check out Flash's External Interface. It will allow you to write most of your app with Javascript, and use Flash only when necessary (wherever HTML5 is lagging behind). http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/javascript-and-actionscript-converse-introduction-to-externalinterface/

Good luck!